# Convergence of $\sin( (1+\sqrt2)^n \pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been working on this for hours and I don't have any idea where to go. I know that $(1 + \sqrt2)^n = a_n + b_n \sqrt2$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are integers, ang $\gcd(a_n, b_b) = 1$. So $$\sin( (1 + \sqrt2)^n) = \cos(a_n \pi) \sin(b_n \pi \sqrt2)$$ but I'm stuck here. I think the limit is 0 but no idea on how to prove it..

Thanks you !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 5):

It is not hard to see that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n+\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n\in\mathbb N.$$Besides, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n=0$ and $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\sin(n\pi)=0$. Therefore,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n\pi\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$\sin((1+\sqrt{2})^n\pi+(1-\sqrt{2})^n\pi-(1-\sqrt{2})^n\pi)$$
and use the addition formulas for the sin-function.